# Atualizar label toda vez que clicar em um botão

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou usando a biblioteca tkinter para a interface do programa, então, na tela teria um label que começasse com o seu texto representado por uma variável de valor '10', então ao clicar um botão, eu queria que ele somasse 1 à primeira variável, porém ele só faz o desejado na primeira vez.

```
from tkinter  import * 
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

num = 10
def soma(a, b):                   
    s = a + b
    num = s
    lb['text'] = num

def bt_click():
    soma(num, 1)

lb = Label(root, text = f'{num}')
lb.place(x = 245, y = 235)

bt = Button(root, text = '+ 1', command = bt_click) 
bt.place(x = 175, y = 235)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis (caso ainda não tenha votado - tb não é obrigatório, mas se vc achou útil, considere votar :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Em Python as variáveis ​​referenciadas apenas dentro de uma função são implicitamente globais.

Porém **se uma variável tiver um valor atribuído em qualquer lugar do corpo da função**, ela será assumida como local, a menos que seja explicitamente declarado como global.

Portanto se quer atribuir valor a uma variável global dentro de um escopo local use a palavra chave [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) antes de usar a variável.

```
def soma(a, b):   
    global num    # informa explicitamente ao interpretador que será utilizado uma variável global dentro desse escopo           
    num = a + b   # a atribuição agora é feita na variável global.
    lb['text'] = num
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Essa função `soma` me parece desnecessária, pois basta você atualizar o conteúdo do botão diretamente:

```
def bt_click():
    lb['text'] = int(lb['text']) + 1
```

Como o texto do botão é uma string, eu uso [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter seu conteúdo para número, e depois somo 1 e atualizo o texto do botão. Então fica assim:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

def bt_click():
    lb['text'] = int(lb['text']) + 1

lb = Label(root, text = '10')
lb.place(x = 245, y = 235)

bt = Button(root, text = '+ 1', command = bt_click) 
bt.place(x = 175, y = 235)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Se quiser **muito** usar a tal função `soma`, então daria para fazer assim:

```
def soma(a, b):
    lb['text'] = a + b

def bt_click():
    soma(int(lb['text']), 1)
```

Eliminei a variável global porque aparentemente não há motivo para mantê-la (mas caso haja, pode usar a [solução da outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/439754/112052) para mantê-la atualizada). Também não tem porque jogar a soma em uma variável `s`, só para depois atribuir `s` ao label. Se não vai usar `s` para mais nada, elimine-a e jogue o resultado da soma diretamente no label.

Se bem que a função `soma` não deveria atualizar o botão, ela deveria somente retornar o resultado da soma e mais nada (e quem chamar a função faz o que precisar com o resultado). Ou seja, algo assim:

```
def soma(a, b):
    return a + b

def bt_click():
    lb['text'] = soma(int(lb['text']), 1)
```

Mas ainda acho exagero para esse caso específico, e eu ficaria com a primeira solução que sugeri, que não usa a função `soma`. Claro que se for fazer várias outras coisas mais complexas, aí vale a pena quebrar em funções menores. Mas para o seu caso específico, acho que não precisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois, dentro do seu método, a variável `num` não é a mesma que a que você declarou. pense que a `num` dentro do método apenas o método pode ver. Para conseguir esse valor, você deve retornar ele, dessa maneira:

```
def soma(a, b):                   
    s = a + b
    num = s
    lb['text'] = num
    return num
```

e para receber esse número, na chamada do método, use:

```
num = soma(num, 1)
```